# How to reset the state of a portlet?

Tags: portlet, websphere-portal

Is it possible to reset the state of a portlet whenever user navigates to that page for the first time?

Comment: How are you maintaining the state currently?

Comment: The setWindowState(WindowState windowState) does not fulfil your purpose?http://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-2.0-apidocs/javax/portlet/PortletURL.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to redirect to clean URL.
As states are managed by URL, cleaning it would be reset the state.